# How can i use XFAFlattener from iText in jruby?

Tags: itext, jruby

I got inspiration from https://github.com/abevoelker/pdf_ravager to create XFA Flattening. I was trying to use the XFAWorker, which is a paid version. I am trying to get the trial version to work with jRuby. XFAFlattener cannot be instantiated since it says that the class cannot be found. I added the license key as well. I am doing all the experiment in jirb.

I am assuming i dont understand how license key works. Any suggestions will be great.

Comment: Unfortunately the repository you linked contains iText 4.2.0, which is a version that was never released by iText Software. Official releases jumped from 2.1.7 to 5.0.0. Anything in between is a fork by a third party.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I am not using that version. I just took inspiration from there.

Comment: Okay. I logged an issue on that repository, you may ignore the above comment.

Comment: You have also sent this question to our sales person in Asia, he will get back to you. However it is definitely possible to use iText in JRuby, I'd like to refer to a blog post one of my colleagues wrote: https://milkedeek.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/itext-on-the-jvm/ and I see no reason why iText add-ons wouldn't work either. Your issue is apparently a matter of getting the actual license key library to work in JRuby and you'll get an answer through the sales support channel.